# Is there a way to generate model codes from DB schema in Lift?

Tags: database, scala, model, lift

All the books, examples, and tutorials tell people how to get schema generated from model code in Scala Lift implementations. Is there any way around, instead?

Is there a way to generate model codes from DB schema in Lift? I am migrating a RoR Web App onto lift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I think not. [There was talk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9526237/115478) about doing such a thing for [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/) (which you can use using lift-squeryl-record), but I don't think it ever happened.